# Python 2.7 possible bug, imported modules "disappears"

Tags: python

I've found something very strange. See this short code below.

```
import os

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pid = os.getpid()
        print "os: %s." %os

    def __del__(self):
        print "os: %s." %os

def temp_test_path():
    return "./[%d].log" %(os.getpid())

logger = Logger()
```

This is intended for illustrative purposes. It just prints the imported module `os`, on the construstion and destruction of a class (never mind the name `Logger`). However, when I run this, the module `os` seems to "disappear" to `None` in the class destructor. The following is the output.

```
os: <module 'os' from 'C:\Python27\lib\os.pyc'>.
os: None.
```

Where is said `os: None.` is my problem. It should be identical to the first output line. However, look back at the python code above, at the function `temp_test_path()`. If I alter the name of this function slightly, to say `temp_test_pat()`, and keep all of the rest of the code exactly the same, and run it, I get the expected output (below).

```
os: <module 'os' from 'C:\Python27\lib\os.pyc'>.
os: <module 'os' from 'C:\Python27\lib\os.pyc'>.
```

I can't find any explanation for this except that it's a bug. Can you? By the way I'm using Windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Can you fix your indentation?

Comment: Please check your indentation - are the `class` and `def` lines supposed to be at the same level?

Comment: @Ray -- I believe that I have fixed the indentation -- You should check it and see though.  I noticed that there were spaces and tabs in there -- It might just be from putting the code in for StackOverflow, but you should run your script with `python -t` to check.

Comment: I'll let one of the real experts chip in, but I don't find this at all surprising -- the order in which the `__del__` for objects is called at program end is arbitrary.  (Can't remember if it's because a dictionary is being iterated over, but I wouldn't be surprised.)  In fact, it's not even guaranteed by the language spec to be called: in PyPy, you won't even *see* the second `os:` line.

Comment: And if you add explicit `del logger` at the end of the script, the logger destructor is going to be called first.

Comment: @DSM -- I don't know if I'm one of the real language experts, but I would be willing to bet that it is based on the order of `globals`.  See my answer :)

Comment: Sorry about the earlier indentation problem, I just copy-pasted from notepad++. Thank @mgilson for correcting the indentation!

Comment: @Fenikso: careful.  `del logger` deletes the *name* 'logger', it doesn't call `__del__`.

Comment: @DSM - I have just tried it, put an infinite loop afterwards to be sure, and it did. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Fenikso: it *may*.  It deletes one reference to it, and if that was the only one, then CPython can call `__del__`.  But there's no obligation to, other Python implementations won't, and even CPython won't if there's another reference.  For example, try `a = A(); b = a; del a`.  The point is, `del` only removes the name.  Whether `__del__` is called is something else entirely, as explained in [this section](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) of the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are relying on the interpreter shutdown to call your `__del__` it could very well be that the `os` module has already been deleted before your `__del__` gets called. Try explicitly doing a `del logger` in your code and sleep for a bit. This should show it clearly that the code functions as you expect.

I also want to link you to this note in the [official documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) that `__del__` is not guaranteed to be called in the CPython implementation.

Comment: Following what you kindly pointed out, isn't that a bit silly on Python's part? This and many other problems with Python are kind of dampening my enthusiasm for Python now.

Comment: @Ray:  I suggest raising your concerns on the Python mailing list.  Often discomfort is caused by thinking in your old programming language rather than in Python.  They should be able to point out if this is the case.

Comment: That `logger` object that is automatically created when this module is imported (last line of my code) is required throughout the execution of my code. It has to be alive right until the very end of the program execution. How do I make sure that del(logger) is executed before this module dies? I can't think of a way right now...

Comment: Aha!  A very specific question.  Post it as a new question and I think you'll get a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

I've reproduced this.  Interesting behavior for sure.  One thing that you need to realize is that `__del__` isn't guaranteed to even be called when the interpreter exits -- Also there is no specified order for finalizing objects at interpreter exit.

Since you're exiting the interpreter, there is no guarantee that `os` hasn't been deleted first.  In this case, it seems that `os` is in fact being finalized before your `Logger` object.  These things *probably* happen depending on the order in the `globals` dictionary.

If we just print the keys of the globals dictionary right before we exit:

```
for k in globals().keys():
    print k
```

you'll see:

```
temp_test_path
__builtins__
__file__
__package__
__name__
Logger
os
__doc__
logger
```

or:

```
logger
__builtins__
__file__
__package__
temp_test_pat
__name__
Logger
os
__doc__
```

Notice where your `logger` sits, particularly compared to where `os` sits in the list.  With `temp_test_pat`, `logger` actually gets finalized **First**, so `os` is still bound to something meaningful.  However, it gets finalize **Last** in the case where you use `temp_test_path`.

If you plan on having an object live until the interpreter is exiting, and you have some cleanup code that you want to run, you could always register a function to be run using `atexit.register`.

Answer (score 3):

Others have given you the answer, it is undefined the order in which global variables (such as `os`, `Logger` and `logger`) are deleted from the module's namespace during shutdown.

However, if you want a workaround, just import `os` into the finaliser's local namespace:

```
def __del__(self):
    import os
    print "os: %s." %os
```

The `os` module will still be around at this point, it's just that you've lost your global reference to it.

Comment: The work-around seems to work, I guess I'll have to do that for now. Thanks Duncan.

Answer (score 2):

This is to be expected. From the The [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> Also, when **del**() is invoked in response to a module being deleted
>   (e.g., when execution of the program is done), other globals
>   referenced by the **del**() method may already have been deleted or in
>   the process of being torn down (e.g. the import machinery shutting
>   down).

in big red warning box :-)

Comment: Thank you @mavroprovato. Do you know if there is a way of ensuring that the `del()` method is called before any modules die?

Comment: I don't think there is... I think it is better to re import the module in the del method as Duncan suggested