# Python how to ensure that __del__() method of an object is called before the module dies?

Tags: python, module, destructor

Earlier today I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984136/python-2-7-possible-bug-imported-modules-disappears) question about the `__del__()` method of an object which uses an imported module. The problem was that `__del__()` wants to make use of the module `os`, but sometimes (not always) the module has already been deleted. I was told that when a Python program terminates, the order in which objects and modules are deleted can be random, and is undefined. However, for my application, I really need to make sure that an object (instance of a class I created) gets deleted before the module (in which the object is instantiated) gets deleted. Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As we told you before, you really shouldn't rely on `__del__` being called when the interpreter exits.  There are two options for doing this properly:

The first is `atexit`

```
import os
import atexit

class Logger(object):   
    def on_exit(self):
        print "os: %s." % os

logger = Logger()
atexit.register(logger.on_exit)
```

This makes sure that your logger gets finalized at exit.

---

*Reading a little more into your problem, since you plan on having a single instance bound to a module which defines the instances's class, the context manager solution below won't work for this since there's no way to stay in the context for the entire execution of your program.  You'll need to use `atexit.register`.  However, from the standpoint of program design, I would much prefer to use a context manager to manage my resources than `atexit.register` if restructuring the code would allow it.

The second <strike>(better*)</strike> way to do it is make your class a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) which executes the cleanup code when you exit the context.  Then your code would look like:

```
import os
class Logger(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print "os:",str(os)

with Logger() as logger:
    #do something ...
```

Comment: Why is a context manager better than atexit.register() in this case?

Comment: @thebjorn -- Because the context manager makes it a lot more natural to work with your class within a function for instance.  with `atexit.register`, you'll keep a reference of your object around long after the object should have been finalized.  It also makes it explicit that the object needs to be finalized which is a really big deal as far as code legibility is concerned.

Comment: Ah. Thank you @mgilson, but now I have to figure out what `atexit` is (never heard of it before), and what the difference between `__init__()` and `__enter__` is, and what the difference between `__del__()` and `__exit__()` is. But thank you!

Comment: @Ray -- Reading your comments on the other question helped me to understand your problem better.  In this case, I'd recommend using `atexit.register` rather than a context manager.  Context managers are good things to know for code which needs to be finalized however, so I'm going to leave that portion of my answer.

Comment: @mgilson. Ooh one more thing, with the `atexit` solution (I assume you mean the module `atexit`), is there a reason you wrote `del()` instead of `__del__()`?

Comment: @Ray -- to prevent `__del__` from being called twice.  You only need to execute your cleanup code once.

Comment: @mgilson. You don't know how grateful I am right now. I've just tried `atexit` but I don't think that suits my particular problem either. My actual `__del__()` function calls another function that uses the `time` module, which also disappears. I can't use `atexit` to register both functions because then the other function will be called twice. It doesn't matter though, I'll find a way to work around this. I'm now going to learn about context managers. Thanks again.

Comment: @DSM -- D'oh.  Don't you hate it when these old, above average scored answers have blaring problems?

Answer (score 4):

Attach a reference to the function with a keyword parameter:

```
import os

class Logger(object):    
    def __del__(self, os=os):
        print "os: %s." %os
```

or bind it to a class attribute:

```
import os

class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.os = os

    def __del__(self):
        print "os: %s." % self.os
```

By creating a local (enough) reference, Python will not look up `os` as a global, but with a local reference, which are stored with the instance or with the function itself, respectively.

Globals are looked up at runtime (which is why the `__del__` function in your other question fails if `os` has already been cleaned up), while a function local is cleared up together with the function object, or in case of a instance attribute, with the instance.

Comment: But this still doesn't guarantee that `__del__` will actually be called.

Answer (score 0):

The previously mentioned usage of using 'atexit' can also be applied by using decorators which I find to be particularly useful. This simply ensures that the decorated function will be called at the termination of the program.

```
@atexit.register
def close():
    print("Closing Program")
```