# Python strange multiprocessing with variable name

Tags: python, multiprocessing

a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import multiprocessing

class Klass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Constructor ... %s" % multiprocessing.current_process().name

    def __del__(self):
        print "... Destructor %s" % multiprocessing.current_process().name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    kls = Klass()
```

run with error when do `current_process` in `__del__`:

```
Constructor ... MainProcess
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current_process'" in <bound method Klass.__del__ of <__main__.Klass object at 0x7f5c34e52090>> ignored
```

if I change a variable name:

```
als = Klass()
```

it get the right result:

```
Constructor ... MainProcess
... Destructor MainProcess
```

and I tried many variable name, some ok, some error.

Why different instance name, will cause multiprocessing module be None in `__del__`?

Comment: I see the same result... that's very weird!

Comment: Same here. Produces the same weird results. So I guess you spotted a bug in `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  see unutbu 's answer

Comment: @Sait see unutbu 's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code raises

```
AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'current_process'"
```

if the global variable `multiprocessing` is deleted before `kls` gets deleted.
In general, the order in which objects are deleted is not predictable. However, [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__):

> Starting with version 1.5, Python guarantees that globals whose name begins with a single underscore are deleted from their module before other globals are deleted; if no other references to such globals exist, this may help in assuring that imported modules are still available at the time when the `__del__()` method is called.

Therefore, if you name the instance `_kls` (with an underscore), then you can be assured that its `__del__` will be called before `multiprocessing` is deleted:

```
import multiprocessing 

class Klass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Constructor ... %s" % multiprocessing.current_process().name

    def __del__(self):
        print "... Destructor %s" % multiprocessing.current_process().name


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _kls = Klass()
```

yields

```
Constructor ... MainProcess
... Destructor MainProcess
```

---

[Other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14986568/190597) of ensuring a `del` method is called before the module is deleted include

- using `atexit`
- using a context manager
- saving a reference to the module as an attribute of `Klass`.

Comment: very thanks! I should be more attention to the *warning* section of python document.