# ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down error using driver.quit() within __del__()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, del

I'm trying to learn selenium for automating some stuff and I get the following error

> Exception ignored in: <function bot.**del** at 0x0351BF10>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "main.py", line 52, in **del**
> File "C:\Users\michael-blaze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 158,
> in quit
> File "C:\Users\michael-blaze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 151, in stop
> File "C:\Users\michael-blaze\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 122, in send_remote_shutdown_command
> ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down

I figured it out the line where it comes from

```
def __del__(self):
   self.driver.quit()
```

My **init** function looks something like this

```
def __init__(self):
   self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

What would cause this problem ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: sys.meta\_path is None, Python is likely shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41480148/importerror-sys-meta-path-is-none-python-is-likely-shutting-down)

Comment: Initially i read that post but it didn't solve my question unfortunately

Comment: Can you rethink your code to use `with webdriver.Chrome(path):` instead? that should clean up properly at the end

Comment: I'm still a noob with python. Can you be more specific when you say use 'with webdriver.Chrome(path)' :)

Comment: self.driver.close() works but it doesn't free up memory running.t

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your issue. Here are the observations:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  class PythonBot:
      def __init__(self,my_string):
      self.my_string = my_string
      self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')

      def send_text(self):
      driver = self.driver
      driver.get('https://www.google.com/')
      WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys(self.my_string)

      def __del__(self):
      self.driver.quit()

  run = PythonBot('Selenium')
  run.send_text()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Exception ignored in: <bound method PythonBot.__del__ of <__main__.PythonBot object at 0x028172F0>>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Soma Bhattacharjee\Desktop\Debanjan\PyPrograms\init_del_in_python_class.py", line 17, in __del__
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 158, in quit
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 151, in stop
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 122, in send_remote_shutdown_command
  ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down
  ```

---

### Analysis

This issue was earlier reported and discussed within [sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3330). Accordingly a [commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/3263) was merged which mentions:

> Changes the order of events to stop a process. Previously. the order was `terminate()` -> `kill()` -> `wait()`. So... it would send a SIGTERM signal to the process, immediately followed by a SIGKILL signal. Since `wait()` is called after the process has already been forcefully stopped, there is nothing to wait on, so it does nothing. The proper sequence should be: `terminate()` -> `wait()` -> `kill()`. That will send a SIGINT, wait for graceful process termination, then send a SIGKILL to forcefully stop it as a last resort.

However, this issue still seems to be surfacing when using `self.driver.quit()` within `def __del__(self):`

Reported this issue in:

- [ImportError: sys.meta_path is None, Python is likely shutting down when calling self.driver.quit() within **del**(self)](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/8571)

---

### Interim Solution

An interim solution would be to call `self.driver.close()` within `def __del__(self):` as follows:

```
def __del__(self):
    self.driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

See if you can structure you code like this:

```py
# stuff before the driver call
with webdriver.Chrome(path) as driver:
    # do your stuff here
    # you can access the driver using the variable 'driver'
# stuff after the driver call
```

In this way once the `with` block is finished, the driver should be cleaned in the best way possible, including forcing Python to wait until closed.

disclaimer: I haven't tested it, just noticed that they have the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods implemented

Comment: your approuch works perfectly but i still wonder why self.driver.quit() doesn't work inside my __del__  destructor function. I wanted to use classes.

Comment: this may be a good reference to understand that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986568/python-how-to-ensure-that-del-method-of-an-object-is-called-before-the-mod. Basically, once you get to `__del__` your interpreter already cleaned up some things. Looking into the code, seems that there are some modules that are imported within the `quit` command, and that may be too late to do that as well